# Unable to run Selenium tests on Internet Explorer using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the below line to start IEDriver but it fails to open.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C://Test//IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Comment: What is the error message are you getting? Please provide a traceback.

Comment: Care to share the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Internet Explorer

Download the latest IEDriver from [LINK](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

```
self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C://IEDriverServer.exe")
self.driver.get("http://python.org/")
```